# Как заставить работать match у sphinx?

Tags: sphinx

Есть товар с sku 2065/3C, он находится запросом (см. файл request1). это обычный запрос, где мы видим, что 2065/3C присутствует в базе

но не находится таким запросом (см. файл request2)

Версии sphinx перебирал разные.

request1 https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzdcxjdhc3k16zi/request1.txt?dl=0

```
MySQL [(none)]> select sku from products where match ('@sku 2065\\\/') limit 1000;
+--------------+
| sku          |
+--------------+
| 2065/1A_     |
| 2065/3+3P_   |
| 2065/О.Т._   |
| 2065/К.Т._   |
| 2065/21+4    |
| 2065/30.M.L  |
| 2065/16+8    |
| 2065/28+8    |
| 2065/90TEK   |
| 2065/18+6    |
| 2065/12+6    |
| 2065/60ARM   |
| 2065/60TEK   |
| 2065/90ARM   |
| 2065/60ARM   |
| 2065/60TEK   |
| 2065/90ARM   |
| 2065/1LMB    |
| 2065/1ML     |
| 2065/1A      |
| 2065/1AB     |
| 2065/10+5    |
| 2065/12+4    |
| 2065/15+5    |
| 2065/18+5    |
| 2065/2ML     |
| 2065/2A      |
| 2065/2AB     |
| 2065/3+3     |
| 2065/4+2     |
| 2065/5+3     |
| 2065/6+3     |
| 2065/8+4     |
| 2065/9+3     |
| 2065/BKT     |
| 2065/BT      |
| 2065/BA      |
| 2065/OKT     |
| 2065/OT      |
| 2065/OA      |
| 2065/KKT     |
| 2065/KT      |
| 2065/KA      |
| 2065/3C      |
| 2065/4C      |
| 2065/5C      |
| 2065/1W      |
| 2065/2W      |
| 2065-PL      |
| 2065/BL      |
| 2065/DL      |
+--------------+
51 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

request2 https://www.dropbox.com/s/4igt0raxneucjnc/request2.txt?dl=0

```
MySQL [(none)]> select sku from products where match ('@sku 2065\\/3') limit 1000;
+------------+
| sku        |
+------------+
| 2065/3+3P_ |
| 2065/3+3   |
| 2065/5+3   |
| 2065/6+3   |
| 2065/9+3   |
+------------+
```

Конфиг https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkiuqf5jm9dpgch/sphinx.conf?dl=0

```
index products
{
    type                = rt
    path                = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/products

    morphology          = stem_enru, lemmatize_ru

    rt_field            = name
    rt_field            = sku
    rt_field            = brand_sku
    rt_field            = code

    rt_attr_multi       = category_list
    rt_attr_uint        = primary_category
    rt_attr_uint        = base_product_id
    rt_attr_bool        = is_gift
    rt_attr_bool        = in_shop
    rt_attr_bool        = in_showroom
    rt_attr_bool        = fast_delivery
    rt_attr_bool        = free_delivery
    rt_attr_bool        = is_sale
    rt_attr_bool        = is_partner_only

    rt_attr_uint        = brand_id
    rt_attr_uint        = views
    rt_attr_uint        = brand_collection_id
    rt_attr_string      = brand_name
    rt_attr_string      = id1c
    rt_attr_string      = name
    rt_attr_string      = sku

    rt_attr_string      = brand_sku
    rt_attr_bool        = is_images
    rt_attr_bool        = is_enabled
    rt_attr_bool        = is_shipment_unavailable
    rt_attr_bool        = is_has_gift
    rt_attr_bool        = is_discontinued
    rt_attr_uint        = width
    rt_attr_uint        = height
    rt_attr_uint        = length
    rt_attr_uint        = weight
    rt_attr_multi       = attribute_values
    rt_attr_multi       = markers
    rt_attr_string      = stock_status

    rt_attr_timestamp   = created_at
    rt_attr_float       = price
    rt_attr_float       = old_price
    rt_attr_uint        = reviews_rating
    rt_attr_string      = condition

    min_prefix_len      = 3
    min_word_len        = 3

    index_exact_words   = 1
    expand_keywords     = 1
    html_strip          = 1

    dict                = keywords
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 256M
}


searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log         = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
    query_log       = /var/log/sphinxsearch/query.log
    read_timeout        = 5
    client_timeout      = 300
    max_children        = 30
    persistent_connections_limit    = 30
    pid_file        = /var/run/sphinxsearch/searchd.pid
    seamless_rotate     = 1
    preopen_indexes     = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    mva_updates_pool    = 1M
    max_packet_size     = 8M
    max_filters     = 256
    max_filter_values   = 4096
    max_batch_queries   = 32
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
}

common
{
    lemmatizer_base = /usr/local/share/sphinx/dicts
}
```

Новый конфиг https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp48nnjvcc9p54u/config.txt?dl=0

```
index products
{
    type                = rt
    path                = /var/lib/manticore/data/products

    rt_field            = name
    rt_field            = sku
    rt_field            = brand_sku
    rt_field            = code

    rt_attr_multi       = category_list
    rt_attr_uint        = primary_category
    rt_attr_uint        = base_product_id
    rt_attr_bool        = is_gift
    rt_attr_bool        = in_shop
    rt_attr_bool        = in_showroom
    rt_attr_bool        = fast_delivery
    rt_attr_bool        = free_delivery
    rt_attr_bool        = is_sale
    rt_attr_bool        = is_partner_only

    rt_attr_uint        = brand_id
    rt_attr_uint        = views
    rt_attr_uint        = brand_collection_id
    rt_attr_string      = brand_name
    rt_attr_string      = id1c
    rt_attr_string      = name
    rt_attr_string      = sku

    rt_attr_string      = brand_sku
    rt_attr_bool        = is_images
    rt_attr_bool        = is_enabled
    rt_attr_bool        = is_shipment_unavailable
    rt_attr_bool        = is_has_gift
    rt_attr_bool        = is_discontinued
    rt_attr_uint        = width
    rt_attr_uint        = height
    rt_attr_uint        = length
    rt_attr_uint        = weight
    rt_attr_multi       = attribute_values
    rt_attr_multi       = markers
    rt_attr_string      = stock_status

    rt_attr_timestamp   = created_at
    rt_attr_float       = price
    rt_attr_float       = old_price
    rt_attr_uint        = reviews_rating
    rt_attr_string      = condition

    min_word_len        = 1

    index_exact_words   = 1
    expand_keywords     = 1

    dict                = keywords
    min_infix_len = 3
    #min_prefix_len    = 2
    enable_star       = 1
}


index productsstemmed : products
{
    path       = /var/lib/manticore/data/test1stemmed
    morphology = stem_en
}

indexer
{
    mem_limit = 256M
}

searchd
{
    listen                       = 9312
    listen                       = 9306:mysql41
    log                          = /var/log/manticore/searchd.log
    query_log                    = /var/log/manticore/query.log
    read_timeout                 = 5
    client_timeout               = 300
    max_children                 = 30
    persistent_connections_limit = 30
    pid_file                     = /var/run/manticore/searchd.pid
    seamless_rotate              = 1
    preopen_indexes              = 1
    unlink_old                   = 1
    mva_updates_pool             = 1M
    max_packet_size              = 8M
    max_filters                  = 256
    max_filter_values            = 4096
    max_batch_queries            = 32
}

common
{
    lemmatizer_base = /usr/local/share/sphinx/dicts
}


root@cs41156:~# dpkg --list | grep manticore
ii  manticore                           2.6.2-180223-0bbd194                                     amd64        Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine
```

Comment: Покажите конфиг sphinx что ли

Comment: @andreymal вот: [конфиг](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tkiuqf5jm9dpgch/sphinx.conf?dl=0)

Comment: Похоже, что версия у вас все же старая. Вот это "morphology      = stem_enru, lemmatize_ru" должно вызывать ошибку "stem_ru and lemmatize_ru clash - NOT SERVING" и такой индекс не должен обслуживаться. Это появилось в 2014-ом. У меня на manticore search 2.6.2 все ок и ищется по "2065" легко.

Comment: @andreymal отредачил изначальный вопрос, посмотрите пожалуйста. Поставил версию Manticore 2.6.2-180223-0bbd194                                     amd64        Fast standalone full-text SQL search engine, скормил [такой конфиг](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xp48nnjvcc9p54u/config.txt?dl=0) Запрос 1 (см. выше в вопросе) находит, запрос 2 не находит...

Comment: @IgorKhrushchev покажите новый конфиг, пожалуйста и покажите как вы вставляете проблемный документ. У меня все равно все работает и request2 находит 2065/3C.

Comment: @ManticoreSearch выше прицепил ссылку на конфиг: http://joxi.ru/5md4o3qUv9PdXm

Comment: request1 (находит) https://www.dropbox.com/s/pzdcxjdhc3k16zi/request1.txt?dl=0

request2 (не находит) https://www.dropbox.com/s/4igt0raxneucjnc/request2.txt?dl=0

Comment: @andreymal, из конфига строчки с решётками поудалять можно? Это же комментарии? А то переновил код в вопрос, а оно в максимальную дину не лезет ((

Answer (score 0):

request2 (`'@sku 2065\\/3'`) не находит документ потому, что min_infix_len в конфиге равно 3 и превышает длину второго слова ("3" - 1 символ). Про это есть соответствующий ворнинг:

```
mysql> select sku from products where match('@sku 2065\\/3');
Empty set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                       |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| warning | 1000 | Query word length is less than min infix length. word: '*3*'  |
+---------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Если поменять min_infix_len на 1 и использовать звездочку, то документ находится:

```
mysql> insert into products values(1,'2065/3C','2065/3C');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> select sku from products where match('@sku 2065\\/3*');
+---------+
| sku     |
+---------+
| 2065/3C |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Без звездочки не работает, потому что минимальная допустимая длина инфикса сейчас 2, просто в данном случае поиск идет по префиксу, который при включении инфиксов тоже включается, но expand_keywords срабатывает только по инфиксу, поэтому нужно вручную добавлять звездочку. Как альтернатива можно отставить min_prefix_len = 1, тогда будет работать без звездочки:

```
mysql> insert into products values(1,'2065/3C','2065/3C');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sku from products where match('2065\\/3');
+---------+
| sku     |
+---------+
| 2065/3C |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал, но не ищет и ворнингов нет. Переиндексацию товаров запускал - тоже не помогает (((

Comment: @IgorKhrushchev покажите новый конфиг, пожалуйста

Comment: Простите, я могу написать вам куда-то для более оперативной связи? У нас тут вообще адский ступор (( Оплачу.

Comment: @IgorKhrushchev Конечно, у нас есть форум, слак и платный саппорт тоже - https://manticoresearch.com/#post-112

Comment: Проблема разрешилась добавлением в конфигурации параметра 
 blend_chars со значениями спецсимволов.